# Making an AI that talks through a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have been working on a small Artificial Intelligence, and I am having trouble with getting the AI to write the answer to a JTextField in a JPanel that is in a JFrame.

```
package iamthethomas.artint;

import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.Random;



public class artint {



@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void main(String[] args) {


    String s;
    String ts;
    String ms;
    String[] howAre;

    howAre = new String[2];
    howAre[0] = "Good, how about you?";
    howAre[1] = "Fine, how 'bout you?";

    String[] speaking;
    speaking = new String[8];
    speaking[0] = "I didn't understand that. Are you speaking Inglish?";
    speaking[1] = "I didn't understand that. Are you speaking Latin?";
    speaking[2] = "I didn't understand that. Are you speaking German?";
    speaking[3] = "I didn't understand that. Are you speaking Mandarin?";
    speaking[4] = "I didn't understand that. Are you speaking Leet?";
    speaking[5] = "I didn't understand that. Are you speaking Greek?";
    speaking[6] = "I didn't understand that. Are you speaking Arabic?";
    speaking[7] = "I didn't understand that. Are you speaking Hebrew?";

    String[] hello;
    hello = new String[3];
    hello[0] = "Hello to you too!";
    hello[1] = "Howdy, par'ner!";
    hello[2] = "G'mornin'";


    Random rand = new Random();
    int i = rand.nextInt(3);
    int j = rand.nextInt(8);
    int k = rand.nextInt(2);
    String[] hi;
    hi = new String[3];
    hi[0] = "Top of the mornin'.";
    hi[1] = "Hey!";
    hi[2] = "Hello!";


    Scanner phrase = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("I am an AI (Artificial Intelligence) talk to me like I'm a human being\nand don't reference Siri.");
    s = phrase.nextLine();


    if (s.toLowerCase().contains("hello")) {
        System.out.println(hello[i]);
        Body.body();
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("hi")) {
        System.out.println(hi[i]);
        Body.body();
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("how are ")) {
        System.out.println(howAre[k]);
        ms = phrase.nextLine();
        if (ms.toLowerCase().contains("bad")) {
            System.out.println("Sorry :(");
            Body.body();
        } else if (ms.toLowerCase().contains("good")) {
            System.out.println("Glad to hear it!");
            Body.body();
        } else if (ms.toLowerCase().contains("great")) {
            System.out.println("I'm happy that you're happy!");
            Body.body();
        } else if (ms.toLowerCase().contains("perfect")) {
            System.out
                    .println("Perfect? Nothing's ever perfect, but you're getting close!");
            Body.body();
        }else if (ms.toLowerCase().contains("fine")){
            System.out.println("Fine? Good!");
            Body.body();
        }
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("beam me up scotty")) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, your TriCorder is in Airplane mode");
        Body.body();
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("hey bro")) {
        System.out.println("Howdy partner");
        Body.body();
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("hal 9000")) {
        System.out
                .println("HAL made some bad choices, lets not talk about him");
        Body.body();
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("glitch in the matrix")) {
        System.out.println("\n /\\_/\\" + "\n( o.o )" + "\n > ^ <");
        System.out.print("\n /\\_/\\" + "\n( o.o )" + "\n > ^ <");
        Body.body();
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("book by its")) {
        System.out
                .println("That's right......say, whats you be readin' right now?");
        ts = phrase.nextLine();
        if (ts.contains("series")) {
            System.out.println("I read that series too!");
            Body.body();
        } else {
            System.out.println("That was a good book");
            Body.body();
        }
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("book by it's")) {
        System.out
                .println("That's right......say, whats you be readin' right now?");
        ts = phrase.nextLine();
        if (ts.contains("series")) {
            System.out.println("I read that series too!");
            Body.body();
        } else {
            System.out.println("That was a good book");
            Body.body();
        }
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("like cats")) {
        System.out.println("I like to pets 'em");
        Body.body();
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("i own goats")) {
        System.out.println("Really?");
        ts = phrase.nextLine();
        if (ts.toLowerCase().contains("yes")) {
            System.out.println("Me too! I have 3");
            Body.body();
        } else if (ts.toLowerCase().contains("no")) {
            System.out.println("Oh, too bad they're so much fun!");
            Body.body();
        }
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("like dogs")) {
        System.out.println("I love 'em!");
        Body.body();
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("what's new")) {
        System.out
                .println("Oh, you know...work, I'm a computer engineer and programmer. Do you program?");
        ts = phrase.nextLine();
        if (ts.toLowerCase().contains("no")) {
            System.out
                    .println("If theres no too much on your schedule, you should get into it!");
            Body.body();
        } else if (ts.toLowerCase().contains("yes")) {
            System.out
                    .println("A fellow coder? Can you guess what language this is written in (Java, Python, C, C++, Obj C, Javascript, or HTML)");
            ts = phrase.nextLine();
            if (ts.toLowerCase().equals("java")) {
                System.out.println("You guessed it!");
                Body.body();
            } else {
                System.out.println("The correct answer was Java.");
                Body.body();
            }
        }
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().equals("quit")) {
        System.out.println("Bye!");
        System.out
                .println("This program is open source, you can add more replies if you like\nA Steampunk Production");
        System.exit(0);
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("how do you do")) {
        System.out
                .println("Oh...I don't know, pretty good I guess. How about you?");
        ts = phrase.nextLine();
        if (ts.toLowerCase().contains("good")) {
            System.out
                    .println("Well, if you're happy, then I'm happy, too!");
            Body.body();
        } else if (ts.toLowerCase().contains("great")) {
            System.out.println("Good, good.");
            Body.body();
        } else if (ts.toLowerCase().contains("awesome")) {
            System.out.println("Cool bruh");
            Body.body();
        }
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("do you have kids")) {
        System.out.println("Yes, 4. Ages 13, 16, 5, 10");
        Body.body();
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("beam me up")) {
        System.out.println("Shoo that fly away first");
        Body.body();
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("do you have pets")) {
        System.out
                .println("Yeah, 3 cats, Jessie Coon James, Milo, and Bella. I also have 3 goats, Rosie, Lily, and Mojang.");
        Body.body();
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("can i have a hug")){
        System.out.println("[~~HUG~~]");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("thanks")){
        System.out.println("You're welcome");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("thank you")){
        System.out.println("You're welcome");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("thnx")){
        System.out.println("yw");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("thx")){
        System.out.println("yw");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("xd")){
        System.out.println(":]");
        Body.body();
    }else if(s.toLowerCase().contains("how much wood could")){
        System.out.println("Well, is it an African wood chuck or an American?");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("1337")){
        System.out.println("1337 baby, like an internet boss!");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("chemistry joke")){
        System.out.println("NaBRO");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("me a joke")){
        System.out.println("I like my coffe like I like my wars, cold!");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("your favorite color")){
        System.out.println("Camoflage");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("you single")){
        System.out.println("Yes");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("you marrie me")){
        System.out.println("No");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("your favorite food")){
        System.out.println("Mac and cheese");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("your favorite band")){
        System.out.println("Beach Boys");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("you have a dog")){
        System.out.println("Yeah, her name is Mattie");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("me a knock knock")){
        System.out.println("Knock Knock!");
        ts = phrase.nextLine();
        if (ts.toLowerCase().contains("whos there")){
            System.out.println("Needle!");
            ts = phrase.nextLine();
            if (ts.toLowerCase().contains("needle who")){
                System.out.println("Needle little money for the movies!");
                Body.body();
            }
        }else if(ts.toLowerCase().contains("who's there")){
            System.out.println("Needle!");
        }
        ms = phrase.nextLine();
        if (ms.toLowerCase().contains("needle who")){
            System.out.println("Needle little money for the movies!");
            Body.body();
        }
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("what is your name")){
        System.out.println("My name is AI, pronounced AL");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("whats your name")){
        System.out.println("My name is AI, pronounced AL");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("what's your name")){
        System.out.println("My name is AI, pronounced AL");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("you a robot")){
        System.out.println("NO! HOW DARE YOU SAY SUCH A PROPOSTEROUS THING!");
        System.out.println("GOOD BYE!");
        System.out.println("**walks away**\n**turns around**\nOUR RELATIOSHIP IS OVER!");
        System.exit(0);
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("siri")){
        System.out.println("I warned you...No Siri references!...SYSTEM SHUTTING DOWN!");
        System.exit(0);
    }else if(s.toLowerCase().contains("how's it going")){
        System.out.println("Good, I just finished College at MIT for computer engineering and programming");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("was work")){
        System.out.println("I had to wake up so early, I almost forgot to take my potion of sleep resistance.");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("is a potion of sleep resistance")){
        System.out.println("Coffee.");
        Body.body();
    }else if(s.toLowerCase().contains("whats new")){
        System.out.println("Oh, you know...work stuff...programming...");
        Body.body();
    }else{
        System.out.println(speaking[j]);
        Body.body();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the Body class:

```
package iamthethomas.artint;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Body {

public static void body() {
    String s;
    String ts;
    String ms;
    String[] howAre;
    howAre = new String[2];
    howAre[0] = "Good, how about you?";
    howAre[1] = "Fine, how 'bout you?";
    String[] speaking;
    speaking = new String[8];
    speaking[0] = "I didn't understand that. Are you speaking Inglish?";
    speaking[1] = "I didn't understand that. Are you speaking Latin?";
    speaking[2] = "I didn't understand that. Are you speaking German?";
    speaking[3] = "I didn't understand that. Are you speaking Mandarin?";
    speaking[4] = "I didn't understand that. Are you speaking Leet?";
    speaking[5] = "I didn't understand that. Are you speaking Greek?";
    speaking[6] = "I didn't understand that. Are you speaking Arabic?";
    speaking[7] = "I didn't understand that. Are you speaking Hebrew?";
    String[] hello;
    hello = new String[3];
    hello[0] = "Hello to you too!";
    hello[1] = "Howdy, par'ner!";
    hello[2] = "G'mornin'";


    Random rand = new Random();
    int i = rand.nextInt(3);
    int j = rand.nextInt(8);
    int k = rand.nextInt(2);
    String[] hi;
    hi = new String[3];
    hi[0] = "Top of the mornin'.";
    hi[1] = "Hey!";
    hi[2] = "Hello!";


    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner phrase = new Scanner(System.in);
    s = phrase.nextLine();


    if (s.toLowerCase().contains("hello")) {
        System.out.println(hello[i]);
        Body.body();
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("hi")) {
        System.out.println(hi[i]);
        Body.body();
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("how are ")) {
        System.out.println(howAre[k]);
        ms = phrase.nextLine();
        if (ms.toLowerCase().contains("bad")) {
            System.out.println("Sorry :(");
            Body.body();
        } else if (ms.toLowerCase().contains("good")) {
            System.out.println("Glad to hear it!");
            Body.body();
        } else if (ms.toLowerCase().contains("great")) {
            System.out.println("I'm happy that you're happy!");
            Body.body();
        } else if (ms.toLowerCase().contains("perfect")) {
            System.out
                    .println("Perfect? Nothing's ever perfect, but you're getting close!");
            Body.body();
        }else if (ms.toLowerCase().contains("fine")){
            System.out.println("Fine? Good!");
            Body.body();
        }
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("beam me up scotty")) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, your TriCorder is in Airplane mode");
        Body.body();
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("hey bro")) {
        System.out.println("Howdy partner");
        Body.body();
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("hal 9000")) {
        System.out
                .println("HAL made some bad choices, lets not talk about him");
        Body.body();
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("glitch in the matrix")) {
        System.out.println("\n /\\_/\\" + "\n( o.o )" + "\n > ^ <");
        System.out.print("\n /\\_/\\" + "\n( o.o )" + "\n > ^ <");
        Body.body();
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("book by its")) {
        System.out
                .println("That's right......say, whats you be readin' right now?");
        ts = phrase.nextLine();
        if (ts.contains("series")) {
            System.out.println("I read that series too!");
            Body.body();
        } else {
            System.out.println("That was a good book");
            Body.body();
        }
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("book by it's")) {
        System.out
                .println("That's right......say, whats you be readin' right now?");
        ts = phrase.nextLine();
        if (ts.contains("series")) {
            System.out.println("I read that series too!");
            Body.body();
        } else {
            System.out.println("That was a good book");
            Body.body();
        }
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("like cats")) {
        System.out.println("I like to pets 'em");
        Body.body();
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("i own goats")) {
        System.out.println("Really?");
        ts = phrase.nextLine();
        if (ts.toLowerCase().contains("yes")) {
            System.out.println("Me too! I have 3");
            Body.body();
        } else if (ts.toLowerCase().contains("no")) {
            System.out.println("Oh, too bad they're so much fun!");
            Body.body();
        }
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("like dogs")) {
        System.out.println("I love 'em!");
        Body.body();
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("what's new")) {
        System.out
                .println("Oh, you know...work, I'm a computer engineer and programmer. Do you program?");
        ts = phrase.nextLine();
        if (ts.toLowerCase().contains("no")) {
            System.out
                    .println("If theres no too much on your schedule, you should get into it!");
            Body.body();
        } else if (ts.toLowerCase().contains("yes")) {
            System.out
                    .println("A fellow coder? Can you guess what language this is written in (Java, Python, C, C++, Obj C, Javascript, or HTML)");
            ts = phrase.nextLine();
            if (ts.toLowerCase().equals("java")) {
                System.out.println("You guessed it!");
                Body.body();
            } else {
                System.out.println("The correct answer was Java.");
                Body.body();
            }
        }
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().equals("quit")) {
        System.out.println("Bye!");
        System.out
                .println("This program is open source, you can add more replies if you like\nA Steampunk Production");
        System.exit(0);
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("how do you do")) {
        System.out
                .println("Oh...I don't know, pretty good I guess. How about you?");
        ts = phrase.nextLine();
        if (ts.toLowerCase().contains("good")) {
            System.out
                    .println("Well, if you're happy, then I'm happy, too!");
            Body.body();
        } else if (ts.toLowerCase().contains("great")) {
            System.out.println("Good, good.");
            Body.body();
        } else if (ts.toLowerCase().contains("awesome")) {
            System.out.println("Cool bruh");
            Body.body();
        }
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("do you have kids")) {
        System.out.println("Yes, 4. Ages 13, 16, 5, 10");
        Body.body();
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("beam me up")) {
        System.out.println("Shoo that fly away first");
        Body.body();
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("do you have pets")) {
        System.out
                .println("Yeah, 3 cats, Jessie Coon James, Milo, and Bella. I also have 3 goats, Rosie, Lily, and Mojang.");
        Body.body();
    } else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("can i have a hug")){
        System.out.println("[~~HUG~~]");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("thanks")){
        System.out.println("You're welcome");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("thank you")){
        System.out.println("You're welcome");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("thnx")){
        System.out.println("yw");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("thx")){
        System.out.println("yw");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("xd")){
        System.out.println(":]");
        Body.body();
    }else if(s.toLowerCase().contains("how much wood could")){
        System.out.println("Well, is it an African wood chuck or an American?");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("1337")){
        System.out.println("1337 baby, like an internet boss!");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("chemistry joke")){
        System.out.println("NaBRO");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("me a joke")){
        System.out.println("I like my coffe like I like my wars, cold!");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("your favorite color")){
        System.out.println("Camoflage");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("you single")){
        System.out.println("Yes");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("you marrie me")){
        System.out.println("No");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("your favorite food")){
        System.out.println("Mac and cheese");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("your favorite band")){
        System.out.println("Beach Boys");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("you have a dog")){
        System.out.println("Yeah, her name is Mattie");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("me a knock knock")){
        System.out.println("Knock Knock!");
        ts = phrase.nextLine();
        if (ts.toLowerCase().contains("whos there")){
            System.out.println("Needle!");
            ts = phrase.nextLine();
            if (ts.toLowerCase().contains("needle who")){
                System.out.println("Needle little money for the movies!");
                Body.body();
            }
        }else if(ts.toLowerCase().contains("who's there")){
            System.out.println("Needle!");
        }
        ms = phrase.nextLine();
        if (ms.toLowerCase().contains("needle who")){
            System.out.println("Needle little money for the movies!");
            Body.body();
        }
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("what is your name")){
        System.out.println("My name is AI, pronounced AL");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("whats your name")){
        System.out.println("My name is AI, pronounced AL");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("what's your name")){
        System.out.println("My name is AI, pronounced AL");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("you a robot")){
        System.out.println("NO! HOW DARE YOU SAY SUCH A PROPOSTEROUS THING!");
        System.out.println("GOOD BYE!");
        System.out.println("**walks away**\n**turns around**\nOUR RELATIOSHIP IS OVER!");
        System.exit(0);
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("siri")){
        System.out.println("I warned you...No Siri references!...SYSTEM SHUTTING DOWN!");
        System.exit(0);
    }else if(s.toLowerCase().contains("how's it going")){
        System.out.println("Good, I just finished College at MIT for computer engineering and programming");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("was work")){
        System.out.println("I had to wake up so early, I almost forgot to take my potion of sleep resistance.");
        Body.body();
    }else if (s.toLowerCase().contains("is a potion of sleep resistance")){
        System.out.println("Coffee.");
        Body.body();
    }else if(s.toLowerCase().contains("whats new")){
        System.out.println("Oh, you know...work stuff...programming...");
        Body.body();
    }else{
        System.out.println(speaking[j]);
        Body.body();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is getting the AI to `.append()` the `String` answer it has for the user.

Comment: So what exactly have you tried with JPanels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code that shows you how to create a simple GUI:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

    frame.add(scrollPane);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                textArea.append("hello\n");
                try { Thread.sleep(500); } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

First of all you need to define a `JFrame` which is the frame which contains the editor. Then define a `JTextArea`, the editor, and make it scrollable through a `JScrollpane`. Add the scrollable editor to the frame and set it visible (show him).

Then I've made a `Thread` which print something on the editor via the `append()` method. It isn't needed but shows you how to use the `append()` method.

Ps: I really think you don't need a `JPanel`.

**EDIT**: I want to clarify once for all: *the `Thread` I used is only an example to show the user how to use the `append()` method*, and, therefore, must be understood precisely in this direction and has nothing to do with EDT, concurrency and so on.

Comment: The main UI should be constructed and updated on the EDT, as should the Swing component method call in the runnable.

Comment: So what would I replace System.out.println("") with?

Comment: After the GUI creation, use the `setText()` or the `append()` method. Take a look at the `JTextArea` API.

Comment: That's not what I mean. I need the program to print the answer that it has through the GUI.

Comment: What's the problem? In my example I showed you how to *create* and *use* a simple GUI composed by an editor and how to print strings on it. Create the GUY yourself and replace the `System.out.println()` with the `append()` where needed.

Comment: wrong answer (could be wokrs in Java 5with luck in Java6), Thread.sleep to block an EDT, more in Concurency in Swing (in Java7 and newer versions don't exist Thread Safe methods in Swing APIs)

Comment: It solved my problem but the it doesn't create a JFrame.

Comment: I want to clarify once for all: the `Thread` I used is only an example to show the user how to use the `append()` method and, therefore, must be understood precisely in this direction and has nothing to do with EDT, concurrency and so on.